# What is the right way to close the listening channel?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, channel

I’m writing a custom channel implementation for WCF using named pipe as the transport. I know there is named pipe support for WCF but I have very particular requirements to write a custom channel. I found pieces of information on the web, a couple of examples where the transport is a file or UDP and after putting into it quite some effort the implementation is almost complete.

There is one last thing I’m trying to understand where the listening channel is supposed to be closed? Is it supposed to be done by WCF or I have to do it? I though it is responsibility of WCF. After all the framework calls AcceptChannel on my implementation of the channel listener, I create an instance of the channel, and give it back to WCF. Now WCF owns the object and I think it should close it when it is not necessary any more.

After WCF received my instance of the channel it calls TryReceiveRequest, in that method I use named pipe waiting on reading bytes. At certain point when the client disposes the client channel I get EndOfStreamException exception at waiting on reading bytes. Then if I return null RequestContext object from TryReceiveRequest WCF breaks the loop where it calls TryReceiveRequest and this is it. I thought after that WCF should call Close on that channel object but no, it doesn’t do it. Of course, I can call Close in the EndOfStreamException catch but it doesn’t feel right. If WCF received an instance of the channel object WCF should call Close, right? What am I doing wrong and how to make it call Close? Do I need to tell WCF somehow that communication is broken by the client and it’s time to close the channel?